# Paper icon theme broken after upgrade with little RAM

Tags: unity, upgrade, icons, icon-themes

After running a package upgrade with little RAM available, my Paper icon theme install is broken. `apt-get purge`ing and reinstalling the package, with reboots after every step, hasn't helped. When I select the Paper icon theme in Unity Tweak Tool, the icons revert back to the default (hideous) Gnome ones.

Just before the icons broke, the following error came up in the graphical update manager:

```
Unpacking paper-icon-theme (version) over (version) ...
gtk-update-icon-cache-3.0: **
Gtk:ERROR/build/gtk+3.0-3sSotQ/gtk+3.0-3.10.8/./gtk/updateiconcache.c:1117:write_bucket: assertion failed: (*offset == ftell (cache))
Aborted (core dumped)
WARNING: icon cache generation failed for /usr/share/icons/Paper
```

Unfortunately, when I pressed 'Report problem', there was apparently not enough free memory to analyse the problem and send a bug report.

How can I fix the theme?

Comment: So, what would be the question? Either: How to send a bug report for the broken theme, How to fix the broken theme, How to install Paper icon theme with little RAM; And how little is the RAM? The list goes on without specifying what is the question...

Comment: @clearkimura How to fix the broken theme was what I was intending.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by deleting `icon-theme.cache` in `/usr/share/icons/Paper/`. To recreate the cache file (which apparently reduces disk usage, according to the man page), run

```
sudo gtk-update-icon-cache /usr/share/icons/Paper/
```

and reselect the icon theme in Unity Tweak Tool. A reboot shouldn't be necessary.